# Jest unable to find style names

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React+Typescript+Webpack (using CSS modules) project that I am trying to write a unit test for. In my unit tests, my unit tests are failing because styles seem to be undefined.

**Update:** If I replace `` style={{backgroundImage: `url(${myImg})`}} `` with `` style={{backgroundImage: `url(test)`}} `` then the test fails with `Expected object: {"backgroundImage": "url(test)"}` so the problem must be to do with how the import of my image is happening in my tests.

In `package.json`, my `jest` object looks like this:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileMock.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "\\.(test|spec)\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ]
  }
```

`fileMock.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

My React component looks like this:

```
import * as styles from './Foo.less';
import myImg from './myImg.png';

export const Foo = () => (
  <div
    className="something"
    style={{backgroundImage: `url(${myImg})`}}
  >
  Some content
  </div>
);
```

I want to test that the style prop contains `myImg.png`. My test for that looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Foo } from './Foo';

test('Foo has myImg in style prop', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Foo />
  );
  expect(wrapper.find('.something').prop('style')).toContain('myImg.png');
});
```

I'd expect this test to pass, however, it fails with the following error:

```
expect(object).toContain(value)

Expected object:
  {"backgroundImage": "url(undefined)"}
To contain value:
  "myImg.png"
```

I'm not too sure what is going on here. When I run the application in my browser, the image displays fine and I can inspect the element and see that `backgroundImage` property is being populated properly.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is strange. Try run test with `--no-cache` option. And also make sure your transform script is actually running (do `console.log` there).

Comment: your `transform` is the same that `react-scripts` uses, so I'm not sure, this does seem like it is set up correctly.